# How to get Access 2010 query to number based on criteria from other columns

Tags: microsoft-access

I have a query where it pulls the ID and Employee columns and I am trying to get Access to populate the data as shown in the 'OrderCol1' and 'OrderCol2' columns of the table below.  As I'm sure you picked up from the example below, I need to have OrderCol1 just increment up 1 each time the Employee changes. And I need OrderCol2 to increment up one while Employee stays the same, and every time it changes, make OrderCol2 start back over at 1.

Is there a way to do this in a query?

[image: example]

Comment: With SQL Server's full SQL support, I'd look into `GROUP BY`, `OVER` and `PARTITION` for a start. Not sure if Access supports those; it should do GROUP BY just fine, but `OVER` and `PARTITION` are somewhat more advanced features that may not be supported.

Comment: Those clauses/functions are great in SQL (and would be perfect for this situation), but unfortunately this solution has to come within MS Access.